# Python problem executing popen in cron

Tags: python, console, cron

I use `popen` to execute commands in a Python script, and I call it via cron.
Cron calls out this script but the behavior isn't the same if I call it by hand.

#### Source:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pp = Popen('/usr/bin/which iptables', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

data = ''
for ln in pp.stdout:
    data = data+ln

if data == '':
    print 'ko'
else:
    print 'ok : '+data
```

#### By hand:

```
# python /home/user/test.py
> : /sbin/iptables
```

#### By cron (in /tmp/err_cron):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/user/test.py >> /tmp/err_cron
ko
ko
ko
```

Why does cron not run this script normally?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally when processes are run from cron, the `PATH` is set to a very restrictive value (the man page for my crontab says `/usr/bin:/bin`). You  may need to add:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin
```

to the top of your crontab file.