# Python cron subprocess Popen calling java jar

Tags: java, python, cron

I have a python program that nicely preprocesses my data when called from the command line, but fails when I call it with cron. There is a step in my pipeline where I read in a gzip file of user data and call a java program that decrypt it before hashing I it. At first my problem was with paths as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602830/python-problem-executing-popen-in-cron) post, but I have fixed that (I think...) and gzip is working properly. The java call is failing in that `output` is being populated with an empty string instead of the decrypted results I normally get.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['gzip', '-dc', input_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', '/home/tristan/preprocess/Decrypt.jar'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?